# Space complexity of Dictionaries-inside-another-Dictionary in Python3

Tags: python, complexity-theory, space-complexity

What is the space complexity of dictionaries inside a dictionary. I guess the abstract idea is:

```
D = { KEY0: { key0_0: "val0_0", key0_1: "val0_1", ... , key0_n0: "val0_n0" } ,
      KEY1: {key1_0: "val1_0", ... , key1_n1: "val1_n1" } ,
      ... ,
      KEYm: { keym_0: "valm_0", ... , keym_nm: "valm_nm" }
      }
```

So I think it's `O(M*N)` and I'm guessing that it's `O(min(N,M)*min(N,M))`, so `O(N^2)`.

Comment: The space complexity with what being the varying parameters in your analysis?

Comment: Each nested dictionary is O(N), the main dictionary is O(M) The combination is O(N*M)

Comment: It's basically just the sum of the lengths of all the dictionaries.